# mapActivity taking almos 1.5 minutes to load everything

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

So, this is my code, it goes to a external database and retrives the first 25 markers within a radius of ( I dont remember if its 100 or 200 km ).

The thing is, the maps are taking about 1.5 minutes to load fully.

Is there any way I can minimize this loading time? It ain't acceptable in my opinion.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapasActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    String sLatitude;
    String sLongitude;
    String sLinguagem;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String sLat;
    String sLng;
    String sTipo;
    String id;
    TextView tvNome;
    TextView tvNext;
    RelativeLayout layoutClickable;
    LatLng markerLatLng;
    Typeface tf;
    Typeface tf2;
    Marker marker;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    Drawable d;
    String sTransition;

    Double dLatitude;
    Double dLongitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa);

        sTransition = "b"; // até contrário ao clickar em algo faz o efeito b

        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/Lobster.ttf");
        tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Cabin-Italic.otf");

        // TESTEEEEE

        d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_background);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        getActionBar().setLogo(
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo_degradee));

        int actionBarTitle = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
                "action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        TextView actionBarTitleView = (TextView) getWindow().findViewById(
                actionBarTitle);
        actionBarTitleView.setTypeface(tf);
        getActionBar().setTitle("Mapactivity");

        /*********************************************************************************
         * INTENTS E PREFS
         *********************************************************************************/

        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",
                MODE_PRIVATE);

        sLinguagem = pref.getString("LINGUAGEM", null);
        sLatitude = pref.getString("LATITUDE", "0");
        sLongitude = pref.getString("LONGITUDE", "0");
        sTipo = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TIPO");

        dLatitude = Double.parseDouble(sLatitude);
        dLongitude = Double.parseDouble(sLongitude);

        // ******************************************************************************
        // TESTES
        // ******************************************************************************

        id = " Finder";

        layoutClickable = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_mapa_botton);
        tvNome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeDoEstabelecimento);
        tvNext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNext);
        tvNome.setText(id);
        tvNome.setTypeface(tf);
        tvNext.setTypeface(tf2);
        tvNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        /*********************************************************************************
         * GOOGLE PLAY
         ********************************************************************************/

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else {
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            /*********************************************************************************************************************
             * PORMENORES PARA O MAPA
             ***************************************************************************************************************/
            googleMap = fm.getMap();
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            // cOISAS PARA TESTES
            // ********************************************************
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude);
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12);
            googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);




            googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {




                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                            R.layout.marker_custom_marker_info, null);
                    TextView tvNomeInfo = (TextView) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.tvMarkerNome);
                    TextView tvIdInfo = (TextView) v
                            .findViewById(R.id.tvMarkerId);

                //  LatLng llMarker = marker.getPosition();

                    tvNomeInfo.setText(marker.getTitle());
                    tvNomeInfo.setTypeface(tf);
                    tvIdInfo.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                    tvIdInfo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    return v;
                }
            });
            // ***************************************************************************

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            /******************************************************************************
             * EVENTO DO LAYOUT
             *****************************************************************************/

            layoutClickable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (id != "Finder") {
                        sTransition = "a";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MapasActivity.this,
                                SingleItemView.class);
                        intent.putExtra("KEY_ID", id);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        new getAllCustomerstask().execute(new ApiConnectorMapas());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            sTransition = "c";
            Intent i1 = new Intent(this, ServicosListActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_listView:
            sTransition = "b";
            Intent i2 = new Intent(this, LOJASListActivity.class);
            i2.putExtra("TIPO", sTipo);
            startActivity(i2);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private class getAllCustomerstask extends
            AsyncTask<ApiConnectorMapas, Long, JSONArray> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapasActivity.this);
            pDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            pDialog.setMessage("A localizar lojas ao pé de si...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
                    "Esconder esta mensagem",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnectorMapas... params) {
            return params[0].GetAllCustomers(sLatitude, sLongitude, sTipo/*
                                                                         * ,
                                                                         * sLinguagem
                                                                         */);
        }

    //  @SuppressWarnings("null")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            /*
             * Códigos Para lista::
             * 
             * id name address promotype distance lat lng tipo foto
             */
            pDialog.dismiss();
            /*
             * if (jsonArray!= null){
             */
            /**********************************************************************************************************************************
             * LAYOUT MARKER
             */
            View icon = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(MapasActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                    .inflate(R.layout.mapa_custom_marker_layout, null);

            View iconPromo = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(MapasActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                    .inflate(R.layout.mapa_custom_promoted_marker_layout, null);


            TextView numTxt = (TextView) icon.findViewById(R.id.tvInfoNome);
            numTxt.setTypeface(tf2);

            List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = null;
                try {
                    json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Double promotype = json.getDouble("promotype");

                    numTxt.setText(json.getString("distance") + " km");
                    if (promotype < 1) {

                        //numTxt.setText(json.getString("distance") + " km");
                        Marker marker;
                        marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .title(json.getString("name"))
                                .snippet(json.getString("id"))
                                .position(
                                        new LatLng(json.getDouble("lat"), json
                                                .getDouble("lng")))
                                // .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE))
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(
                                                MapasActivity.this, iconPromo)))

                        );

                        googleMap
                                .setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                                        id = marker.getSnippet();
                                        tvNome.setText(marker.getTitle());
                                        tvNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                        return true;
                                    }
                                });
                        markers.add(marker);
                    } else {
                        //numTxt.setText(json.getString("distance") + " km");
                        //String sAlpha = "0.45";
                        //Float fAlpha = Float.parseFloat(sAlpha);
                        marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .title(json.getString("name"))
                                .position(
                                        new LatLng(json.getDouble("lat"), json
                                                .getDouble("lng")))
                                /*
                                 * .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(
                                 * BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE))
                                 * /*.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                 * .fromResource(R.drawable.pin))
                                 */
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(
                                                MapasActivity.this, icon)))
                                /*.snippet(json.getString("id")).alpha(fAlpha)*/);

                        googleMap
                                .setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                        id = marker.getSnippet();
                                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                                        tvNome.setText(marker.getTitle());
                                        tvNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                });

                        markers.add(marker);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                /*
                 * } json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 * 
                 * listId.add(json.getString("id"));
                 * listName.add(json.getString("name"));
                 * listAddress.add(json.getString("address"));
                 * listPromo.add(json.getString("promotype"));
                 * listDistance.add(json.getString("distance"));
                 * listLat.add(json.getString("lat"));
                 * listLng.add(json.getString("lng"));
                 * listTipo.add(json.getString("tipo"));
                 * listFoto.add(json.getString("foto"));
                 * listRank.add(json.getString("ranking"));
                 * listIdd.add(json.getString("id"));
                 */
            }
        }
    }

    /**********************************************************************************
     * CLASS QUE VAI TRANSFORMAR O LAYOUT NUM BITMAP
     */

    public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels,
                displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
                view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        /*
         * sTransition = a - single item- check sTransition = b - back ou
         * listview - check sTransition = c - searchview - check
         */

        if (sTransition.equals("a")) {
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.para_esq_baixo,
                    R.anim.para_esq_baixo);
        }
        if (sTransition.equals("b")) {
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.para_dir_cima,
                    R.anim.para_dir_baixo);
        }// bottom to top
        if (sTransition.equals("c")) {
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.from_bottom, R.anim.to_top);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should profile your code and determine what exactly is taking so long. Is it the latency of the request? Is adding each marker slow? Are there simply very many markers?

Answer (score 0):

A few things come to mind:

Are you running the app on an emulator or real device? (I would expect this to be very slow on an emulator)

Could it be that the query you are running is pulling back too much data, querying inefficiently, or just plain slow across the network?

You can add `Log` statements in each of your methods to see where your app is spending the most time- that will point you to the bottleneck.

Comment: Good question, The query shouldn't take long since I'm using the same query as I used for a list view ( wich loads in two or 3 secons ), I'm running on a real device.

I'll probably use the log statements ! I rarelly use them so I didn't remember it ! Good point !!